# window.onload vs document.ready dupes

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I found a whole bunch of unlinked duplicates that I don't have enough caffeine in me to know what to do with right now, so here they are:

- [Difference between $(window).load() and $(document).ready() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)
- [What is the difference between $(window).load and $(document).ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182016/what-is-the-difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready)
- [window.onload vs. body.onload vs. document.onready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474037/window-onload-vs-body-onload-vs-document-onready)
- [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)
- [JavaScript window.onload versus body.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701008/javascript-window-onload-versus-body-onload)
- There are possibly others.

To me, it's irrelevant if it's about the jQuery case vs the... not jQuery case (e.g. I'd say `window.onload` and `$(window).load()` are the same topic in this context).

In any case I don't know what to do with these. Some are older, some are more popular, some have a more well-written question, some have better answers, some have `body.onload` thrown in to add excitement. Seems like some fun and complex combination of duplicate links and merging are in order.

I'll let you guys decide. I'm not going to touch them.

Comment: Someone with a gold JavaScript tag badge should be able to determine what to do with these easily, and make quick work of them if they are duplicates. Thanks for pointing it out.